# Sampling Bernoulli random variables in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Given a 1D tensor containing the means of a Bernoulli distribution, how do I sample a corresponding 1D tensor with the given means?

TensorFlow only seems to have `random_normal` and `random_uniform` functions implemented. I could use something complicated like:

```
tf.ceil(tf.sub(tf.random_uniform((1, means.get_shape()[0])),means))
```

but the `ceil` function has no gradient defined in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TFr1.0, `tf.select` is deprecated in favor of `tf.where`. Furthermore, the answer given by @keveman should compare the uniform random sampling with < 0, neither with > 0.5 nor with > 0:

```
    means = tf.constant([.3,.8])
    sample = tf.where(tf.random_uniform([1, 2]) - means < 0, 
      tf.ones([1,2]), tf.zeros([1,2]))
    with tf.Session(''): sample.eval()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `tf.select`, which is differentiable.

```
means = tf.constant([.3,.8])
a = tf.select(tf.random_uniform([1, 2])- means > 0.5, tf.ones([1,2]), tf.zeros([1,2]))
with tf.Session(''): a.eval()
```

Comment: tf.select works! Shouldn't the condition be > 0, instead of >0.5?

Comment: `tf.select` and `tf.cond` may be differentiable, but the `tf.random_uniform` op says it's not differentiable. Does that make the selections or branches in this control op non-differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

[I've seen](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deep-learning-model-rbmrestricted-boltzmann-machine-deepak-kumar/) also the following trick as a way of sampling from the Bernoulli distribution:

```
tf.nn.relu(tf.sign(means - tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(means))))
```

Comment: Apparently this version zeroes the gradient when backpropagating. It's much faster than a `tanh` or sigmoid though.