# Gradients of Bernoulli Samples

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, distribution

I'm trying to calculate the gradients of the samples from a Bernoulli distribution w.r.t. the probabilities `p` (of a sample being `1`).

I tried using both the implementation of the Bernoulli distribution provided in `tensorflow.contrib.distributions` and my own simple implementation based on this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487598/sampling-bernoulli-random-variables-in-tensorflow). However both methods fail when I try to calculate the gradients.

Using the `Bernoulli` implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import Bernoulli

p = tf.constant([0.2, 0.6])
b = Bernoulli(p=p)
s = b.sample()
g = tf.gradients(s, p)

with tf.Session() as session:
    print(session.run(g))
```

The above code gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Using my implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

p = tf.constant([0.2, 0.6])
shape = [1, 2]
s = tf.select(tf.random_uniform(shape) - p > 0.0, tf.ones(shape), tf.zeros(shape))
g = tf.gradients(s, p)

with tf.Session() as session:
    print(session.run(g))
```

Same error:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Is there a way to calculate the gradients of Bernoulli samples?

(My TensorFlow version is 0.12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot backprop through a discrete stochastic node for obvious reasons. As gradients are not defined.
However if you approximate the Bernoulli with a continuos distribution controlled by a temperature parameter, yes you can.

This idea is called reparametrization trick and is implemented in the RelaxedBernoulli in Tensorflow Probability (or also in TF.contrib library)

[Relaxed bernoulli](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/RelaxedBernoulli)

You can specify the probability `p` of your Bernoulli, which is your random variable, et voilà.